# Should the bit in my impact driver have free play?

Tags: powertools, screwdriver

I bought a cheap impact driver and I noticed that the bit is moving inside the chuck, like back and forth. Is this normal, like part of the hammer mechanism, or should the bit stay fixed?

Comment: Is it an impact driver or a hammer drill? Those are two different tools.

Comment: it is a impact driver

Comment: Which direction is "back and forth"?

Comment: forward and backward, like a drill bit inside a SDS plus chuck

Answer (score 2):

### It's normal

If this is an impact *driver* (see below)

[image: Impact Driver]

then it uses a 1/4" hex chuck. Most use a simple ball-detent system to lock bits in place, which allows for some slip, especially forward and backward.

If you got an impact *wrench* (see below)

[image: Impact Wrench]

then it would be a problem, but if you were getting an impact wrench, you likely wouldn't be asking this question.